# What is "bootsect.bak" file?

Tags: windows, boot, bootloader

What is `Bootsect.bak` backup file? Is this file a copy of boot loader or boot sector? if it's a boot sector's copy, why it's needed? because MBR is a fixed sector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bootsect.bak is a backup of the primary Bootsect.dos. It is created by default by old Windows operating systems when any boot modifications occur. It can be safely deleted, as it is only a back-up unlinked to the actual boot sector.

Tip: Bootsect.dos is used to boot into the non-Windows NT operating systems. Bootsect.dos is created for example by Windows NT Setup. The boot sector found in sector 0 of drive C is copied into Bootsect.dos before Setup writes the Windows NT boot sector. The if you want to dual-boot with previous operating systems (DOS, W95, W98), the file is required, because it's their actual boot sector.

Comment: Thank you but I misunderstood the difference between boot loader and boot sector?! so what this backup file contains exactly? because I don't understand boot sector correctly according to wikipedia boot sector is MBR or VBR.

Comment: @Tootip, the boot sector ( the first sector of a partition ) contains the boot loader.  If you had dos installed, then there was a dos boot sector there, and when upgrading to WinNT, it copies the dos boot sector to bootsect.dos, so that after it replaces the dos boot sector with its own boot loader code, it can still boot dos by loading that file.

Comment: Yes, the sector is the actual location of the HDD and the loader is the file located on that sector that starts up an operating system. The .bak file is just a copy of the original one (.dos) but it is not located in a boot sector.